# Android Studio Firebase query search returning object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been programming this part for a whole week, and couldn't find a solution. 
Firebase database looks like:
Firebase database structure

[image]

FIREBASE -> Students (Database) ->

```
{0}
|- ISIC: 1234567
|- name: "Vladimir"
|- password: "vlad"
|- indeks: "111/11"
|- meals
    |-{0} - amount: 15
    |       name: breakfast
    |-{1} - amount: 2
    |       name: lunch
{1}
|- ISIC: 98765
|- name: "John"
|- password: "doe"
|- indeks: 999/99
|- meals
    |-{0} - amount: 18
    |       name: breakfast
    |-{1} - amount: 20
    |       name: lunch
,...,
{n} (nodes)
|- (Data)
|- (Data)
```

When I click the button for Login, where Username is indeks and password is typed, I would like first to query the database to **find the Student which has that indeks** (by username) and check **if the password of that student is exactly like in database**.

My code looks like:

```
EditText userName;
EditText pass;
Button logIn;

DatabaseReference dbStudents;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    logIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

    dbStudents =
```

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("students");

```
    logIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //some code which I don't know
        }
    });
}
```

My trouble is how to retrieve the entire object Student from Firebase and use it after the login is successful. 
Have been using: `Query, addListenerForSingleValueEvent and orderBy().getData()`, but couldn't my problem of finding the value by entered String, and retrieving as an object Student.

THANKS IN ADVANCE! :)

**UPDATE!!**

```
public void getKey() {
        dbStudents = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("students");
        dbStudents.orderByChild("indeks").equalTo(userName.getText().toString())
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            key = snapshot.getKey();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }
```

With this I can get the key of node (student) which contains "indeks" value (entered as username), but now I need to get retrieve as object **Student** using the key (String) from Firebase Database. How can I do it?

**UPDATE 2!!**

Meal class:

```
public class Meal {
    private int amount;
    private String name;

    public Meal() {

    }

    public Meal(int amount, String name) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Meal{" +
                "amount=" + amount +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Student class:

```
public class Student {
private int ISIC;
private String born;
private String contact;
private String description;
private String imagePath;
private String indeks;
private String issued;
private Meal[] meals;
private String name;
private String password;
private String studies;
private String validity;

    public Student() {

    }

    public Student(int ISIC, String born, String contact, String description, String imagePath,
                   String indeks, String issued, Meal[] meals, String name, String password,
                   String studies, String validity) {
        this.ISIC = ISIC;
        this.born = born;
        this.contact = contact;
        this.description = description;
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
        this.indeks = indeks;
        this.issued = issued;
        this.meals = meals;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.studies = studies;
        this.validity = validity;
    }

    public int getISIC() {
        return ISIC;
    }

    public String getBorn() {
        return born;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getImagePath() {
        return imagePath;
    }

    public String getIndeks() {
        return indeks;
    }

    public String getIssued() {
        return issued;
    }

    public Meal[] getMeals() {
        return meals;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getStudies() {
        return studies;
    }

    public String getValidity() {
        return validity;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "ISIC=" + ISIC +
                ", born='" + born + '\'' +
                ", contact='" + contact + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", imagePath='" + imagePath + '\'' +
                ", indeks='" + indeks + '\'' +
                ", issued='" + issued + '\'' +
                ", meals=" + meals +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", studies='" + studies + '\'' +
                ", validity='" + validity + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public void setISIC(int ISIC) {
        this.ISIC = ISIC;
    }

    public void setBorn(String born) {
        this.born = born;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }

    public void setIndeks(String indeks) {
        this.indeks = indeks;
    }

    public void setIssued(String issued) {
        this.issued = issued;
    }

    public void setMeals(Meal[] meals) {
        this.meals = meals;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setStudies(String studies) {
        this.studies = studies;
    }

    public void setValidity(String validity) {
        this.validity = validity;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?a login class?

Comment: @Eminem Yes. I have 2 TextViews, username and password. Each student has specific indeks and password alongside name, ISIC etc. When I enter "indeks" value and password the app must search for that student that has "indeks" I've entered and check if the password entered matches his, and then I can retrieve his values, entire child node (ISIC, name, indeks, password, meals, birth, validity etc.). But can't find a solution that helps to go through each node in firebase database to find a specific one with "indeks" entered as username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this approach in order to get each user password, but instead of saving 0, 1, 2 , 3 i would suggest saving userID as main node for each user, so you can get from the user you need the password , this method instead will get you all the passwords from all the users, replace the autogenerated 0 , 1 , 2 ,3 with `mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();`

```
 logIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                mRef.child("students").child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try {
                    for(DataSnapshot snap :  dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                   YourPojoClass obj = snap.getValue(YourPojoClass.class);
                    String password =obj.getPassword();
                     //here compare your local password inserted in your editText with the one pulled from firebase


    }
                }catch (Exception ex){
                 //error

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
             //cancelled
            }
        });
    }
```

remember, YourPojoClass.class will be a class with setters and getters wiht the exact name of your database variables

Exactly this is `YourPojo.class`

```
public class Student {
    private int ISIC;
    private String indeks;
    private Meal[] meals;
    private String name;
    private String password;
}
```

just remember to do setters and getters for it !

**UPDATE !**

So , now since you get that key you can access to the data inside it

```
public void getKey() {
        dbStudents = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("students");
        dbStudents.orderByChild("indeks").equalTo(userName.getText().toString())
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            key = snapshot.getKey();
                            Student std = snapshot.getValue(Student.class);
                            String password = std.getPassword();
                            String name = std.getName(); 
                            //... And so on with the other data


                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }
```